# How do I make tkinter highlight written text when I click it in a textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code. I am creating a password manager, but I want to include example emails/passwords in the textboxes, but when the user clicks on the textbox, the text will be highlighted or disappear, sort of like websites when you are creating an account. Could you please help on how to do that on tkinter please. (I am not an expert so please don't include anything too advanced)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import choice, randint, shuffle
import pyperclip


def generate_password():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

    password_letters = [choice(letters) for _ in range(randint(8, 10))]
    password_symbols = [choice(symbols) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]
    password_numbers = [choice(numbers) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]

    password_list = password_letters + password_symbols + password_numbers
    shuffle(password_list)

    password = "".join(password_list)
    password_entry.insert(0, password)
    pyperclip.copy(password)


def save():
    website = website_entry.get()
    email = email_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    if len(website) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Oops", message="Please make sure you haven't left any fields empty.")
    else:
        is_ok = messagebox.askokcancel(title=website, message=f"These are the details entered: \nEmail: {email} "
        f"\nPassword: {password} \nIs it ok to save?")
        if is_ok:
            with open("data.txt", "a") as data_file:
                data_file.write(f"{website} | {email} | {password}\n")
                website_entry.delete(0, END)
                password_entry.delete(0, END)


window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)
logo_img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
email_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
website_entry.focus()
email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
email_entry.insert(0, "example@example.com")
password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

generate_password_button = Button(text="Generate Password", command=generate_password)
generate_password_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
add_button = Button(text="Add", width=36, command=save)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code that may solve Your issue:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Entry


def in_pass(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')
    event.widget.config(show='*')


def in_widget(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')


root = Tk()

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.insert(0, 'sample')
entry1.pack()
entry1.bind('<FocusIn>', in_widget)

entry2 = Entry(root)
entry2.insert(0, 'sample')
entry2.pack()
entry2.bind('<FocusIn>', in_pass)

root.mainloop()
```

so basically `.bind()` binds an event to a widget so when that event gets triggered it calls the given function. important to note that it also returns a variable so the given function should have an argument for that even if it is not used (or use `lambda x:`).

In the case of `in_pass()` it also sets the widget so that everything typed in there is hidden as an asterix while `in_widget()` just clears the widget.

for selection You can use this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry


def in_widget(event):
    event.widget.select_range(0, 'end')


root = Tk()

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.insert(0, 'sample')
entry1.pack()
entry1.bind('<FocusIn>', in_widget)

root.mainloop()
```